# how to i can return value in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I fix this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcbetaSite.Models.RegClass'.

```cs
public  ActionResult Register(RegClass NewUser)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    try
    {
      using (DBClassesDataContext DB = new DBClassesDataContext())
      {
        var name = NewUser.Name;
        ModelState.Clear();
        DB.Dispose();
        ViewBag.Message = name;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
    }
  }
  return View(User);
}
```

Register Class

```
@model MvcbetaSite.Models.RegClass

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
```

Comment: Your questions lacks any information what you are trying do. You basically saying "here is the code, fix it". This is not how questions should be asked here. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User is a type System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal, you specify

```
@model MvcbetaSite.Models.RegClass
```

in the view. Your view is expecting MvcbetaSite.Models.RegClass, not System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal.

Comment: I told you exactly why it's happening. Don't specify @model to be RegClass

Answer (score 0):

With

```
return View(User);
```

you are passing a global variable into the view (which is from the `System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal` namespace)

What you probably want to do is passing your `newUser` variable into the view (which is the expected type by your view)

```
@model MvcbetaSite.Models.RegClass
```

Comment: i want save in sql (linQ to sQl)
var DB = new DataClasses1DataContext();
          
            
           DB.Psave(NewUser.Name,NewUser.LastName);